# Firebase Firestore : How to convert document object to a POJO on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

With the Realtime Database, one could do this :

```
MyPojo pojo  = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyPojo.Class);
```

as a way to map the object, how does one do this with `Firestore`?

**CODE :**

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("app/users/" + uid).document("notifications").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document != null) {
                    NotifPojo notifPojo = document....// here
                    return;
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("FragNotif", "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

With a `DocumentSnapshot` you can do:

```
DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
if (document.exists()) {
    // convert document to POJO
    NotifPojo notifPojo = document.toObject(NotifPojo.class);
}
```

Comment: Will this carryover the document id?

Comment: any idea what kind of deserializer this is using? i would like to configure some directives in my pojo for the deserializer if possible. Kind of like what Jackson provides. I'm trying to deserialize to an enum

Comment: I found an answer to keep document id : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999773/2529315

Answer (score 7):

**Java**

```
    DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
if (document.exists()) {
    // convert document to POJO
    NotifPojo notifPojo = document.toObject(NotifPojo.class);
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
 val document = future.get()
 if (document.exists()) {
    // convert document to POJO
     val notifPojo = document.toObject(NotifPojo::class.java)
  }
```

It is important to remember that you must provide a default constructor or you will get the classic deserialization error. For **Java** a `Notif() {}` should suffice. For **Kotlin** initialize your properties.

Comment: Initializing the properties for my data class was the key for me. I had a parameter that was not initialised. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but this is what I have so far.

```
NotifPojo notifPojo = new Gson().fromJson(document.getData().toString(), NotifPojo.class);
```

EDIT : i'm now using what's on the accepted answer.