# can we retrieve the auto id in android which was generated by cloud functions using cloud firestore triggers

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I stored the document creation of auto - generated id using cloud functions in firestore. Now I need to retrieve these triggered auto id in android.By using these I id I have to update the field .  Is it possible to do these process ? If Possble how can we retrieve that id in android

> By using cloud functions

```
var addDoc = db.collection('deyaPayUsers').doc(userId).collection('Split').doc(userId).collection('ReceivedInvitation').add({
                          SenderName: FirstName,
                          Amount:ams,
                          SenderID:id,
                          ReceiverId:userId,
                          ReceiverPhoneNumber:userData.PhoneNumber,
                          SenderAutoId:splitid,
                         }).then(ref => {
                          console.log('Added document with id:', ref.id);// here auto - Id is created  I need to get
                          });
```

Now these added document id I need to retrieve in android . How to do these?

> My database Structure

```
    /deyaPayUsers.     // collection
    /qT7ETq07uafXEMJmPJbgrOtHaoo1//authentication id
    /Split //collection
    /qT7ETq07uafXEMJmPJbgrOtHaoo1 // authentication - id
    /SentInvitations // collection
/auto -id // here the document is created  I need the auto id in android
```

Comment: Answer to this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995080/how-do-i-get-the-document-id-for-a-firestore-document-using-kotlin-data-classes?rq=1

Comment: @kiwi What I need is to get the triggered  document id created using cloud functions in android

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the id that you want to be retrieved.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated my question .

Comment: @AlexMamo Did you  get the solution

Comment: So to understand better, you are generating that id with Cloud Functions and you want to get in your Android app, right? But you just provided the code, not the database structure. You can download it form Firebase Concole or at least provide us a screenshot for it.

Comment: @AlexMamo I had updated by providing the database structure

Comment: Why are you generating a random id and not a custom id that you already have? In order to be able to use in your Android app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167462/discussion-between-lahari-areti-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Please explain me for a better understanding.