# Convert Firestore document to map of objects

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, generics, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore document has data in the following format

```
{
    m1: {
        name: "first"
    },
    m2: {
        name: "second"
    },
    m3: {
        name: "third"
    },
    ...
}
```

[image: Firestore document]

The field names are not known in advance. But each field is of map type, containing `name` field.

I'm trying to convert this document to a map of type `<String, Listing>`, where `Listing` is the data class with `name`.

```kotlin
data class Listing(
    val name: String = ""
)

data class ListingDoc(
    val listingMap: Map<String, Listing>? = null
)
```

I tried the below [code to convert the document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52416163/7721443) without success. `document.toObject()` works when the object fields are known in advance and present in the data class.

```kotlin
        db.collection("Listings")
            .document("trial").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    try {
                        Timber.d("Got document ${document.data}")
                        val listingDocument = document.toObject(ListingDoc::class.java)
                        Timber.d("Got listings: $listingDocument")
                    } catch (exception: Exception) {
                        Timber.d("Error converting listings: ${exception.message}")
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the logcat output

```
2020-08-14 15:27:16.317 19258-19258/com.myapp D/StoreViewModel$getListings: Got document {m1={name=first}, m2={name=second}}
2020-08-14 15:27:16.324 19258-19258/com.myapp W/Firestore: (21.5.0) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for m1 found on class com.myapp.store.ListingDoc
2020-08-14 15:27:16.327 19258-19258/com.myapp W/Firestore: (21.5.0) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for m2 found on class com.myapp.store.ListingDoc
2020-08-14 15:27:16.328 19258-19258/com.myapp D/StoreViewModel$getListings: Converted listings: ListingDoc(listingMap=null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
document?.data?.forEach { item ->
    val fieldName = item.key
    val fieldValue = item.value
}
```

You will have to iterate over result and transform it to `ListingDoc`.

Comment: Using `document.get("trial")` gives a null value. Here `trial` is the document name, not a field. I tried your code with `document.getData()` but it gives error `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Comment: this code produce error :java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to