# Firestore : Get an array of object in a document

Tags: java, android, firebase

So, in my application I want to display mutiple informations about a recipe. In a recipe you can see a category, a name... And a list of ingredients. I want to get this list for display in details of recipe.

[image: Database]

For the moment (in screen) it's possible to see name, category, completion time, difficulty and number of peoples.

[image: Base screen]

Now on this screen, the result I want to get :

[image: New result]

I get it by manually adding objects to the list.

```
ingredients.add(new Ingredient("Test", "1500"));

IngredientsAdapter adapt = new IngredientsAdapter(ViewRecette.this, R.layout.adapter_ingredients, ingredients);
listIngredients.setAdapter(adapt);
```

Now for this to work I am trying to use this code but I get this error.

```
ingredients = (ArrayList<Ingredient>) documentSnapshot.get("Ingrédients");

IngredientsAdapter adapt = new IngredientsAdapter(ViewRecette.this, R.layout.adapter_ingredients, ingredients);
listIngredients.setAdapter(adapt);
```

And the error is :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.learncooking, PID: 21971
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.example.learncooking.Ingredient
    at com.example.learncooking.IngredientsAdapter.getView(IngredientsAdapter.java:40)
    at com.example.learncooking.ViewRecette$1.onEvent(ViewRecette.java:103)
    at com.example.learncooking.ViewRecette$1.onEvent(ViewRecette.java:82)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(DocumentReference.java:504)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8387)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

I am trying to solve this problem thank you in advance for your answers.

**EDIT 1**

So I am now trying to use POJO but I don't really understand how to do this. I am using the following code (I'm not sure about this) but how do I use it to display it ?

```
DocumentSnapshot document = (DocumentSnapshot) documentSnapshot.get("Ingrédients");;
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        IngredientPOJO notifPojo = document.toObject(IngredientPOJO.class);
                    }
```

And the "POJO" file :

```
public class IngredientPOJO {

@SerializedName("ingredient")
@Expose
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

public IngredientPOJO() {

}

public IngredientPOJO(List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}

public List<Ingredient> getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}

public void setIngredients(List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I also modify a few small items here.

```
private TextView nomRecette, tempsTotal, diff, nbPersonne, cat;
private ImageView receteImage;
private ListView listIngredients, listEtapes;
ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients;
ArrayList<Etapes> etapes = new ArrayList<>();

private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
private DocumentReference documentReference;
private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_recette);

    receteImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPhotoRecetteView);
    nomRecette = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomRecetteView);
    cat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCatégorie);
    tempsTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTempsTotal);
    diff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDifficulté);
    nbPersonne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNombrePersonnesView);
    listIngredients = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvIngredientsView);
    listEtapes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvEtapesView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String i = intent.getStringExtra("ID");

    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Recettes").document(i);
    documentReference.addSnapshotListener(ViewRecette.this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {// Display data in TextView
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                    nomRecette.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Nom"));
                    cat.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Catégorie"));
                    tempsTotal.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Temps"));
                    diff.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Difficulté"));
                    nbPersonne.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Nombre de personnes"));

                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        IngredientPOJO notifPojo = documentSnapshot.toObject(IngredientPOJO.class);
                        ingredients =  new ArrayList<>();
                        ingredients.addAll(notifPojo.getIngredients());
                    }

                    IngredientsAdapter adapter = new IngredientsAdapter(ViewRecette.this, R.layout.adapter_ingredients, ingredients);
                    listIngredients.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And finally here is the new error :

```
2021-05-03 21:25:28.367 5485-5485/com.example.learncooking E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.learncooking, PID: 5485
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:588)
    at com.example.learncooking.ViewRecette$1.onEvent(ViewRecette.java:98)
    at com.example.learncooking.ViewRecette$1.onEvent(ViewRecette.java:83)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(DocumentReference.java:504)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: You may need to convert each object to your pojo. You can't directly cast this to an arraylist. See this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639393/firebase-firestore-how-to-convert-document-object-to-a-pojo-on-android

Comment: @MayurGajra I have edited my question with what I am using now, I don't really know how to continue...

Comment: Now add that to the `ingredients`  list. Just Make sure `ingredients` is not null.

Comment: If I try to use "ingredients.add(notifPojo)" this is not accepted because the list needs ingredient and not ingredientPOJO. Sorry I'm probably stupid but I'm doing something wrong :-/

Comment: I have posted the answer. Because, it wasn't fit for the comment. so try that out and let's continue discussion  there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change few things.

Inside the `IngredientPOJO` class change `Object ingredient;` to `List<Ingredient> ingredients;` and also the getter, setter methods accordingly.

Then below this line.

`IngredientPOJO notifPojo = document.toObject(IngredientPOJO.class);`

Get list from that object and add all.

As following example:

```
IngredientPOJO notifPojo = document.toObject(IngredientPOJO.class);
ingrediants.addAll(notifPojo.getIngredient())
```

Comment: I modified as you suggested to me but a new error arises, so I modify the POJO file in the question then add an EDIT 2.

Comment: @JorisRicard Make sure of 2 things. 1) `ingredients` or `notifPojo`  is not null. 2) You're using the correct key `Ingrédients` in the `SerializedName` in the class `IngredientPOJO`

Comment: I modified the IngredientPOJO file trying all possible SerializedName. I also tested if ingredients or notifPojo was null and it is not the case they both output a variable and the error persists.

Comment: @JorisRicard As far as i can see it must be `ingredients = (ArrayList<Ingredient>) documentSnapshot.get("Ingrédients");` You need to remove `(ArrayList<Ingredient>)` part from this line. If error still persists. Then Can you please write a comment beside a line where this error is occurring in your edit2?

Comment: If I remove (ArrayList<Ingredient>) it does not accept the line because "Required type:
ArrayList <com.example.learncooking.Ingredient> and Provided : Object "

Comment: @JorisRicard Yes. Because that's not supposed to be array list directly. just assign a new empty `arraylist`  to it. Don't directly cast it. because that stuff is done by. `toObject`.

Comment: @JorisRicard `ingredients =  new ArrayList<>();` like this. If you have already done that, then just remove this line `ingredients = (ArrayList<Ingredient>) documentSnapshot.get("Ingrédients");` You just need to make sure that list is not null before adding items to it.

Comment: So it looks like this and I still have the same problem, it's unbelievable ...
 : `if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                            IngredientPOJO notifPojo = documentSnapshot.toObject(IngredientPOJO.class);
                            ingredients =  new ArrayList<>();
                            ingredients.addAll(notifPojo.getIngredients());
                        }`

Comment: @JorisRicard Can you please update your code with all the changes that i have suggested in your question?

Comment: Sure, I modify IngredientPOJO as well as my EDIT 2 by adding the whole from the beginning of the code to the point that does not work.