# Getting Data from Firestore Never Completes Successfully

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm new to NoSQL databases, but I'm attempting to use Firestore with an Android mobile application I'm developing.

I can write to the DB without any issues, but I can't read data. See code below:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document("abc@gmail.com");

docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                User userFromDB = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
            }
        });
```

When I was debugging, **program execution didn't enter the 'onSuccess' function.**

The code I'm using is based off the documentation ([Get Data with Cloud Firestore - Custom Objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)). I made sure that the 'User' fields in my code match the ones in the DB, and they all have 'get' methods.

Also, these are my rules:

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if true
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Consider adding an `onFailure` handler too, to see if that fires and if so, with what error.

Comment: Please add the onFailure, as Frank van Puffelen already commented, and tell us if you get something printed out?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added an on onFailure listener, but program execution jumps  past it as well...

Answer (score 0):

The `onSuccessListener` is for write actions to the database. For getting data you need to use the `onCompletedListener` as shown in the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data):

```java
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document("abc@gmail.com");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm attempting to retrieve a custom object. If you go to the 'Custom Object' section in the documentation, an OnSuccessListener is used. I don't mind trying out an OnCompleteListener, but do you know how I could convert the task.getResult() to a User object? document.toObject(User.class) doesn't seem to work with the onCompleteListener

Comment: The `DocumentSnapshot` is always the same class. And yes as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639393/firebase-firestore-how-to-convert-document-object-to-a-pojo-on-android you should be able to convert it to your `User` class. Just make sure to have a proper constructor for it.